# Cannot convert lambda expression to type int because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my the following, and how to fix it:

```
        //filterItem.Value is a string array - It is being conerted into an int array
        var intFilters = Array.ConvertAll(filterItem.Value, s => int.Parse(s));

        //Returns an IQueryable<int> for all items in this context that are also in intFilters
        var ids = Context.table1.Where(a => intFilters.Any(y => y == a.domId)).Select(x => x.domId);

        //query is an IQueryable
        query = query.Where(x => specUnidsNullable.Contains(y => y == x.Id));
```

The aim of the above is to get just the records from `query` that are also contained in `ids`

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type int because it is not a delegate type
```

I have also tried this:

```
var ids = idsNullable.Where(x => x > 0);
```

Which works fine - the reason I did this was to see if the problem was that `ids` could not be converted into a lambda type expression.

There are many questions about this error, but none seem to address my particular issue that I can see...

Comment: Replace `specUnidsNullable.Contains(y => y == x.Id)` with `specUnidsNullable.Contains(x.Id)`?

Comment: @Evk simple mistake I should have spotted that - if you write that as the answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`specUnidsNullable.Contains(y => y == x.Id)` calls LINQ `Contains` method which expects single value of given type (`int` I suppose in this case), and you are passing expression there. So change to either

```
specUnidsNullable.Contains(x.Id);
```

or

```
specUnidsNullable.Any(y => y == x.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue will be resolved after you install EntityFramework and add using System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.